# 'module' object is not callable Django

Tags: django, django-views

views.py

```
 for user in users:
     #for profile in RegistrationProfile.objects.filter(user=user):
     #if profile.activation_key_expired():
     salt = sha_constructor(str(random())).hexdigest()[:5]
     profile.activation_key = sha_constructor(salt+user.username).hexdigest()
     user.date_joined = datetime.now()

     user.save()
     profile.save()
     #if Site._meta.installed:
     site = Site.objects.get_current()
     # else:
     site = RequestSite(request)

     profile.send_activation_email(site)

     context.update({"form" : form})
     return render_to_response("registration/registration_complete.html", context)
```

imports of my views:

```
import django.contrib.sessions
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from mail_templated import EmailMessage
from django.db.models import Sum
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE 
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils.hashcompat import sha_constructor
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
import random
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site, RequestSite
```

this is giving me error ' module' object is not callable..can anyone tell me why? plz tell me what i am missing

Comment: I would try changing `random()` to `random.random()`, but without your actual traceback, it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: could you update your question with 'import' section?

Comment: can u plz tell mme whats the profile import?

Comment: when I wrote 'import section', I meant the part of your views.py, where you import modules

Answer (score 13):

I think you should check your imports. `random` is both a module name and a function inside a module. If you have

```
import random
```

Then you need to call `random.random` instead of just `random`.

Comment: Issue happened to me while moving from "app/forms.py" to "app/forms/formX.py" all my form during big code refactor, imports needed to change accordingly and load the Form instead of the file