# Django 'module' object not callable

Tags: python, django, typeerror

Hi I am working on a class project where I handle medical information. So I thought of using the INDIVO server for that. I am trying to install the indivo_ui_server. I am getting an error, I have installed the patterns package also. The package holds three files and a **init**.py. I am trying to install in **windows**.

[image]

The below code is `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls.defaults import include

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # HARDCODED APP PATHS!! (keep in alpha order)
    (r'^apps/allergies/',       include('apps.allergies.urls')),
    (r'^apps/labs/',            include('apps.labs.urls')),
    (r'^apps/medications/',     include('apps.medications.urls')),
    (r'^apps/problems/',        include('apps.problems.urls')),
    (r'^', include('ui.urls'))  # Everything else to indivo
)
```

The below code is `__init__.py` (from patterns package):

```
def patterns(func):
    empty_argspec = inspect.ArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
    assert inspect.getargspec(func) == empty_argspec, 'Pattern function should not have arguments'

    # TODO: make it not as weird and dirty
    func.__globals__['Mismatch'] = Mismatch

    tree = get_ast(func)
    transform_function(tree.body[0])
    return compile_func(func, tree)
```

Can anyone explain me why I am getting this error.

I have also tried suggestions from [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16230769/5039470) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929628/5039470)

Traceback:

[image]

Comment: add a full traceback and indivo_ui_server.py code

Comment: @TonyRoczz Out of curiosity, just to see if that is the issue , can you try - `from django.conf.urls import include` instead of the defaults one.

Comment: The last line doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to include the main urls.py file into itself?

Comment: @AnandSKumar initially the import had only `from django.conf.urls import patterns, include` and I was getting import error('include'). then only i changed the include import

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am only trying to install the indivo_ui_server. [https://github.com/chb/indivo_ui_server]

Comment: I don't understand why you are modifying anything at all then. That project has `include('ui.urls')` in its last line. Why are you changing it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was just trying to rectify the error. Sorry my mistake

Comment: @AjayGupta indivo_ui_server is not a file its package github.com/chb/indivo_ui_server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import problem was solved by just importing everything from urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
```